# [algorithm/md5]: what is the detailed verification process in file sharing?

Tags: security, encryption, md5, verification, file-transfer

I read the wiki-page of "Cryptographic Hash Function" today.
And I got to know that, md5 has been applied in verification of file.

There is something I can't figure out, here it is.

Suppose I want to download a file(.exe, .iso, whatever) from a website.
1.Does the server first transfer the md5 code of the file to me? 
  If so, how do I store the md5 code? store the code in a file?

2.When the downloading is done, how do I start the verification process?
  Am I supposed to do the verification manually or the downloader (be it a chrome explorer download tool) does the verification automatically?

3.If the file I'm downloading is intercepted by some Hacker on the internet, then will the Hacker know what the file is ?
  And how to prevent the interception?

thank you.

Comment: 1 MD5 is a checksum. 2 dunno if there are some plugins to do this in chrome. 3 These hash functions are one way, they are designed to be difficult to revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to previous answers, the purpose of the MD5 published on download websites has nothing to do with crackers (man-in-the-middle attacks). It's just to make sure you downloaded it correctly. If some bits were corrupted for whatever reason, the software mightn't run. Security is much more complicated to set up than one little hash, but luckily your browser knows how to deal with that: whenever you connect over TLS (SSL, https) it will set up a secure connection. Just by watching how much data is sent, even though he can't see what the data is, an attacker may be able to guess which file you're downloading.

1. MD5 checking is entirely manual. You download it or copy and paste it yourself.
2. Every operating system should come with an md5 program; Windows is probably the only one that doesn't. Google for one if you have the misfortune of needing to.
3. With md5 alone, he certainly can see what the file is. The only way to prevent the interception is to use encryption, which most sites provide using https URLs.

Edit: What is an MD5? It's just the value of a little calculation done with all the parts of the file. You send the file, and do the calculation yourself using the md5 program, and check that you get the same value as is listed on the website. The calculation is clever, and if one or more bits of the file are corrupted, the calculated MD5 value will change, so you know that the download didn't work and you need to download again.

Comment: do you mean the man-in-the-middle just knows how how data is sent, but he can't not copy the data-stream?

Comment: one more question, you just mentioned in your answer that: if the man-in-the-middle can get the md5 of the file I'm downloading, then he can figure what the file is. Why? Just because according to the md5 code, he can figure the file's name and location on the server?

Comment: If you use TLS/SSL (https) then yes, there is no way any attacker in the middle, between you and the server, can see any of the data sent. If he's sitting on one the internet routers between you and the server though, he can see that the server just sent you 271MB of information, say.

Comment: Another question, to prevent interception, use encryption. Encryption is done by server, right? And when downloading is done, I gotta decrypt it using the specific algorithm specified by the server, right?

Comment: Without encryption, a man in the middle can probably do anything. It's hard to get in the middle in the real world, but once you're there it's likely you can do anything. Again, the MD5 has nothing to do with security.

Answer (score 1):

The file and the MD5 hash of the file are transferred separately.  You are expected to calculate the MD5 hash of the file for yourself and compare it with the downloaded version.  If they match then the files are the same.  Think of MD5 as a more elaborate version of a checksum.

If you want to prevent interception then you need to encrypt the file, which is a separate question.  If you want to ensure the the file is truly the original and you haven't been fooled by a false copy, with false MD5 hash, then look at HMAC.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably browser plugins that will let you do hash-verification automatically. I haven't researched any previously.

A website will usually provide a hash, in hex format, next to the download link.

Once you have downloaded the file, you 'feed' it to a tool which will calculate the hash of the file. Almost all programming languages will have the ability to do this, and there are many googable tools to do so.

If the hash that you generated yourself matches the one shown on the website you know that the file is not corrupt / is the correct one.

MD5 is the most common hash function used to do hash verification. It is not advised to use for security purposes anymore, but it is perfectly fine to verify a file's contents are correct (in 'casual' circumstances).

Digital signing is also used to ensure a file is correct and was generated by a known person/authority/site.

Comment: MD5 is still great for security when collisions aren't an issue (which they sometimes aren't). Fine, with caution.

Comment: @lvo, "A website will usually provide a hash, next to the download link", really? I never notice that.

Comment: @Nicholas for file verification, collisions are a huge issue. Specific attacks on md5 involve appending data to the input while keeping the hash the same. I would never consider md5 'great for security' when US-CERT has called it 'cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use'.

Comment: Yes; for file downloads MD5 would be lousy as a security tool. That's not what it's being used here for though. If you're a MITM, you can send a different file and a different MD5, and save yourself the work. Long salted passwords though are fine, for example. Lots of legacy specs use MD5 in ways that are still acceptable, so it has plenty of safe and legitimate uses even for security. Not the best choice for a new standard though.

Comment: @lvo, yes, I saw it. And when I download the file, will the server send me the file's md5 or I just copy the md5 code manually ?